# CSV file locked by "another user" after creating through batch file/SSMS job

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssms, sql-server-agent

So I have this batch file that is running through SSMS SQL Server Agent as a job.

```
@echo off
title This will be the batch script to create our 3 .csv files for Scott.

sqlcmd /S MYSERVER /d QWI /E /Q "SELECT [geography], current_year, [quarter], industry AS sector, ethnicity, [A0] AS Race0, [A1] AS Race1, [A2] AS Race2, [A3] AS Race3, [A4] AS Race4, [A5] AS Race5, [A7] AS Race7 FROM (SELECT [geography], race, current_year, [quarter], industry, ethnicity, HirAS FROM QWI.dbo.RaceEthnicity) p  PIVOT(SUM(HirAS)  FOR race IN( [A0], [A1], [A2], [A3], [A4], [A5], [A7] )) AS pvt WHERE [geography] = '53077' AND current_year = '1990' AND [quarter] = '3' ORDER BY current_year, pvt.geography, sector, ethnicity" /s"," /o "RaceEthnicityResults.csv"
```

Basically, I'm creating a csv file with a query using sqlcmd in the batch file. Everything runs properly and the file is created with the right information inside. The issue is that when I access the file, it can only be used as a "read only" file because it is being used by "another user". I know this is probably because the process is not being closed/killed properly, but SQL Server Agent is showing a success and the job does finish. I am running the process as an "sa".

I have tried adding everything to the end of the batch file,
EXIT
EXIT /b
/c
WAIT
PAUSE
call taskkill /f /im notepad.exe
exit /b 0
and basically any combination thereof, but with no luck in changing the issue so far. Any tips here?

Comment: Run As Administrator will work for you

Comment: Thanks, but running as the "sa" is running as the System Admin. Unfortunately, this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: You sure you're not using -q instead of -Q? One of them leaves SQLCMD open and one doesn't

Comment: its a .bat file.  you run the scheduled task or Cmd OS step as a user that is an admin on the computer running the job.  i tested it. it works.  don't run it as sa - that is a SQL server account

Answer (score 0):

Well, so my temp fix for now was to move the sqlcmd directly to SQL Server Agent in one of the tasks instead of calling the batch file. This was recommended by a colleague and it did the trick. I would like to know if anyone else has had success killing a task like this, etc. and what steps they used though. Just for future jobs.
:)